# Ownership of equipment purchases during Marie-Curie Individual fellowship

Tags: marie-curie

I know there is a related question [Does equipment purchased with grants stay with the PI?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/61293/does-equipment-purchased-with-grants-stay-with-the-pi) but I'm not sure if Individual Marie-Curie Fellowship follow different rules. I am talking about personal equipment like computers, monitors, etc. not lab equipment like pipettes or microscopes. It is true that technically the funding is given to the host institution but the project is self-standing and the Fellow is not a permanent staff, if that makes any difference.

Comment: If you really want to know: Ask your institution. Otherwise, just wait and see what happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience, this depends on the rules of the host institution. Some institutions will allow researchers to keep the equipment purchased (as well as books etc.), while others want to retain it for themselves after the end of the fellowship. This can be the case even if the equipment in question has lost most of its value over the duration of the fellowship, or the institution already has the books in their library etc.

Comment: ... some institutions also might not formally allow to keep the equipment (I guess this is problematic, since it is public money), but might just silently ignore if you keep it.