# How can lab equipment be transfered when the PI changes universities?

Tags: funding, job-search

I've seen these answers:
[Does equipment purchased with grants stay with the PI?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/61293/does-equipment-purchased-with-grants-stay-with-the-pi)
[What happens to equipment purchased using a startup package after an academic leaves the university?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/18581/what-happens-to-equipment-purchased-using-a-startup-package-after-an-academic-le)

However, I want a little more detail on a legend that I've heard that if the new university is offering you start-up funds, then you can buy back your old stuff using the start-up funds at fair prices for used equipment. How does this get negotiated? Does this ever actually happen in practice, or is it a myth?

My lab has a lot off stuff that I've acquired over several years. Some of it I bought with start-up, some I bought with external grant funds, and some I bought with (eek!) my personal money. There are numerous things that I scavenged from other labs. Some of the stuff in my lab is old and somewhat broken (a laptop with a glitchy screen). If I were to get a position at another university, how does this stuff get sorted out?

I'm working at a US university and the new university would be in the US or Canada.